# Parsing multiple XML objects in one file

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have the following input string which is from a 10MB text file. Sometimes there are \n and other values between the xml elements sometimes not.

`string data = "\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>\n<element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>\n \n<element2><sub>3</sub></element2>\n \n<element2><sub>4</sub></element2>";`

now I want this string by `element1` and `element2` XML nodes

the result in this case should be

```
output[0] = "<element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>";
output[1] = "<element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>";
output[2] = "<element2><sub>3</sub></element2>";
output[3] = "<element2><sub>4</sub></element2>";
```

i've tried

```
string[] output= input.Split(new string[] { "<element1>", "<element2>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

but it throws outofmemory exceptions and the delemiter is being removed at splitting.

and

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<root>"+data +"</root>");
```

throws a exception

is there a easy way to parse those xml elements out of my text file?

Comment: Whereever you get the invalid XML from: talk to him and ask to provide valid XML. Everything else is a hack and will break sooner or later.

Comment: each XML for itselve is valid - but they are seperated with metadata and linebreaks

Comment: Can you please tell what exception is thrown when you try to load it into an XmlDocument.

Comment: @OguzOzgul _System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it_

Comment: I recommend removing the \n at the beginning of the document and trying the XmlDocument approach again..

Comment: @Byyo: the error message is self explaining... the xml is invalid because of the linebreak at the beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to remove the xml header and then put the root node. After that, you can use XDocument to parse and select needed elements.

```
    string data = "\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><element1 value=\"3\"><sub>1</sub></element1>\n<element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>\n \n<element2><sub>3</sub></element2>\n \n<element2><sub>4</sub></element2>";

    //Clear whitespace and parse out the header
    data = data.Trim();
    var pos = data.IndexOf("?>") + 2;
    data = string.Concat("<root>",data.Substring(pos, data.Length - pos), "</root>");

    var xml = XDocument.Parse(data);

    //Nodes will have all the elements1, 2... etc.
    var nodes = xml.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.Contains("element"));

    //if you need to load to string list.
    var items = new List<string>();
    foreach(var node in nodes)
    {
        items.Add(node.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Whereever you get the invalid XML from: talk to him and ask to provide valid XML. Everything else is a hack and will break sooner or later.

The not recommended hacky and unstable version:

`"<root>"+data +"</root>"` gives you the following XML

```
<root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <element1 value="3"><sub>1</sub></element1>
    <element1><sub><element>2</element></sub></element1>
    <element2><sub>3</sub></element2>
    <element2><sub>4</sub></element2>
</root>
```

which is invalid because the processing instruction is not at the beginning.

Remove the processing instruction and it should work. Finding the first `"?>"` and removing everything before sounds quite safe to me. In real XML you'd have to consider multiple processing instructions like `<?xml ...?>` and `<?xml-stylesheet ... ?>`.